# Can I use JOSM for drawing office plan and render this map with mapsfourge library for android?

Tags: android, maps, openstreetmap

I just want to know the best way to draw office plan and using this plan in android app for indoor navigation.

I have discovered few variants

1) Using Android canvas and own map protocols

- will take a lot of time. I have tried this issue but have failed with outofmemory with huge maps

2) Using frameforks and standart map protocols

- is it possibe to use OSM map protocol to draw office plan? Or there are another ways to draw office plan?

Answer (score 0):

You should draw the office plan in JOSM. Your OSM data will be easy to maintain and evolve. In addition, OSM data will enable you to add a few features to your app such as POI, routing...

Depending on which map SDK you pick, you might have an additional step to embed tiles.